# List users from two joined tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I've these two tables:

___Hotels

```
|-------------|------------|
| HOT_HotelId | HOT_Name   |
|-------------|------------|
|           1 |    Hotel A |
|           2 |    Hotel B |
|-------------|------------|
```

___UsersHotelsLink

```
|--------|------------|-------------|
| UHL_Id | UHL_UserId | UHL_HotelId |
|--------|------------|-------------|
|      1 |          1 |             |
|      2 |        131 |           1 |
|      3 |        131 |           2 |
|--------|------------|-------------|
```

I would like to list hotels from `___Hotels` for user in `___UsersHotelsLink`.

So, I'm using this working query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ___UsersHotelsLink
LEFT JOIN ___Hotels 
    ON ___UsersHotelsLink.UHL_HotelId = ___Hotels.HOT_HotelId
WHERE HOT_Status != "inactive"
    AND UHL_Status != "inactive"
    AND UHL_UserId = 131
ORDER BY HOT_Creationdate ASC
```

This working when the user (131) has a hotel into `___Hotels` table. But if I replace `131` by `1` (witch is the super admin), it doesn't work. It doesn't return any row.

I would like to have one row return.

What I making wrong please ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you want a row to be returned when searching by a user without a `hotelid`.  Assuming so, your `where` criteria is negating the `outer join` and thus causing no rows to be returned.  Move it to the `on` condition and it should return the user with `null` hotel data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ___UsersHotelsLink
LEFT JOIN ___Hotels 
    ON ___UsersHotelsLink.UHL_HotelId = ___Hotels.HOT_HotelId 
        AND HOT_Status != "inactive"
WHERE UHL_Status != "inactive"
    AND UHL_UserId = 131
ORDER BY HOT_Creationdate ASC
```

Comment: Perfectly what I wanted. Thanks.